# Dynamically creating @property for defined NSObject Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dynamic properties in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592391/dynamic-properties-in-objective-c)
>   [How can I add properties to an object at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819092/how-can-i-add-properties-to-an-object-at-runtime)

Is there a way to actually create properties in runtime dynamically in iOS?

I am experimenting something here, and just wanted to see if it be possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use [class_addMethod](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_addMethod) to add the getters and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties are mapped to methods so you can add properties dynamically the same way you add [methods dynamically](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html) using -[NSObject forwardInvocation:] and -[NSObject methodSignatureForSelector:] though you will have to use method syntax to call these methods and it can get complicated if you want to use primitive type properties.

Comment: could you please give some sample codes?

Answer (score 1):

you can generate types dynamically using ivars and methods, but there is not a means to get all the functionality of a declared property via one or two runtime calls.

a handful of functions should be all that is needed to accomplish the common routines, but a complete implementation would require some work and some syntactical noise.